# django form wizard as_view() example fails with AttributeError

Tags: django, django-forms

I am new to django, and am trying to work with form wizards.  I am following the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/), and trying out the following example from it:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView

class ContactForm1(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    sender = forms.EmailField()

class ContactForm2(forms.Form):
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

class ContactWizard(SessionWizardView):
    pass # I tried with a done() method as well, just to be sure.

initial = {
    '0': {'subject': 'Hello', 'sender': 'user@example.com'},
    '1': {'message': 'Hi there!'}
}
wiz = ContactWizard.as_view([ContactForm1, ContactForm2], initial_dict=initial)
form1 = wiz.get_form('0')
form2 = wiz.get_form('1')
```

But the above throws the following error at the line `form1 = wiz.get_form('0')`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fw.py", line 19, in <module>
    form1 = wiz.get_form('0')
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_form'
```

Is this a bug in the documentation, django itself, or (most likely) something wrong with my code?  I am using django 1.4.1 on Linux (Ubuntu).

A google search shows only two relevant links: [one from django IRC](http://django-irc-logs.com/2012/may/29/), and one from [Django Brasil](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-brasil/W9QtG1qBOP4), but none of the links have any solution.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I was wrong. I read the source code and it returns a function from its superclass `TemplateView` and not an instance of itself, which leads me to believe that the documents are there only for "show".

Comment: @limelights thanks for the update.  Maybe it *is* a bug in django.

Comment: More likely the docs, if you hook it up normally via your `urls.py` it'll work as expected. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported this documentation error to Django team in [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19880) and it is now fixed in the [master](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#providing-initial-data-for-the-forms).

It should be:

```
wiz = ContactWizard.as_view([ContactForm1, ContactForm2], initial_dict=initial)(request)
```

Comment: Thanks!  This makes much more sense.